# Check if script calls itself

Tags: scripting

Let for example i am running the script printScript.sh .How can I check inside if the caller was printScript.sh ?In order words to check if we have recursion?

Comment: What do you want/need to do? This is awfully convoluted, if you define a recursive function you'd take care *not* to have to worry who calls it.

Comment: set an environment variable, and increment it: `export IN_PRINT_SH=$((IN_PRINT_SH+1))`.

Answer (score 0):

[This SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20572934/get-the-name-of-the-caller-script-in-bash-script) has an accepted answer that shows how to get the name of the caller script in a bash script as follows:

```
PARENT_COMMAND=$(ps -o comm= $PPID)
```

Comment: Recursion could be indirect... and an ancestor's command could be another name for the same script.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest and robust way probably is with shell environment variable. We will use `$MY_COOL_SCRIPT_REC` as a variable name dedicated to our script.

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

# test indrect command calling, can be removed afterwards
PARENT_COMMAND=$(ps -o comm= $PPID)
echo parent is $PARENT_COMMAND

# check recursion
if [ -z ${MY_COOL_SCRIPT_REC+x} ]; then
  echo no recursion
else
  echo in recursion, exiting...
  exit  # stop if in recursion
fi
# set an env variable local to this shell
export MY_COOL_SCRIPT_REC=1

# run again in another disowned shell
nohup ./test.sh &
```

with output

```bsh
$ ./test.sh
parent is bash
no recursion
$ nohup: appending output to 'nohup.out'

# content of 'nohup.out'
parent is systemd
in recursion, exiting...
```

---

As a bonus it can be easily adopted to limits recursion depth

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

PARENT_COMMAND=$(ps -o comm= $PPID)
echo parent is $PARENT_COMMAND

# set env var if not exists
export MY_COOL_SCRIPT_REC="${MY_COOL_SCRIPT_REC:-0}"
# check recursion
if [ "${MY_COOL_SCRIPT_REC}" -le "3" ]; then
  echo recursion depth ${MY_COOL_SCRIPT_REC}
else
  echo exiting...
  exit  # stop
fi

# increment depth counter
export MY_COOL_SCRIPT_REC=$(($MY_COOL_SCRIPT_REC+1))

# run again in another shell
nohup ./test.sh &
```

with output

```bsh
$ ./test.sh
parent is bash
recursion depth 0
$ nohup: appending output to 'nohup.out'

# content of 'nohup.out' (the rest of outputs are all not displayed in same shell)
parent is systemd    
recursion depth 1    
parent is systemd    
recursion depth 2    
parent is systemd    
recursion depth 3    
parent is systemd    
exiting...
```

---

The use of `nohup` is to test if the script works even if the script is indrectly called. The variable `$MY_COOL_SCRIPT_REC` is also local to processes spawned by the `./test.sh` script only.